# complex analysis- simple poles of the gamma function

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, gamma-function, residue-calculus, analytic-continuation

I know that the $\Gamma(z)$ has simple poles at $0, -1, -2,...$

Does that mean $\Gamma(z/2)$ has simples pole at $0, -1/2,-1,...$?

Also, $Res(\Gamma,-k)=(-1)^k/k!$, so is the residue of $\Gamma(z/2)$ the same but with $k/2$?

Comment: I'd say you'd have to multiply the original poles by two to get the poles of $\;\Gamma\left(\frac z2\right)\;$ , not divide them by two...

Comment: Sorry, can you explain why?

How does that affect the residue function?

Answer (score 2):

If $\;k\;$ is a pole of $\;\Gamma(z)\;$ , then

$$0=\frac1{\Gamma(k)}=\frac1{\Gamma\left(\frac{2k}2\right)}\implies 2k\;\text{ is a pole of}\;\;\Gamma\left(\frac z2\right)$$

Now you try to work out the residues...